# How can I update many properties of an element without listing them individually in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyway I can reduce this code? I already tried shortening it to the shortest I can possibly think. Is there any possible shortening techniques there is?

```js
document.getElementById('switcher').addEventListener('click', (param1) => {
    let dmbody = document.body.style;
    let dmbutton = document.getElementById('switcher').style;
    if(param1.target.value == "Off"){
        param1.target.value = "On";
        param1.target.textContent = "Dark";
        dmbody.backgroundColor = "var(--darkbg-color)";
        dmbody.color = "var(--darktxtcolor)";
        dmbutton.backgroundColor = "var(--darkbg-color)";
        dmbutton.color = "var(--darktxtcolor)";
        dmbutton.setProperty("border", "1px solid #FFF");
    } else {
        param1.target.value = "Off";
        param1.target.textContent = "Light";
        dmbody.backgroundColor = "var(--lightbg-color)";
        dmbody.color = "var(--lighttxtcolor)";
        dmbutton.backgroundColor = "var(--lightbg-color)";
        dmbutton.color = "var(--lighttxtcolor)";
        dmbutton.setProperty("border", "1px solid #000");
    }
})
```

```html
<button id="switcher" value="Off">Light</button>
```

Comment: You'd get much less JS code if you use CSS for styling. Would be much easier to maintain, as well.

Comment: [Toggle](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a single class on a parent node using the [`classList` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Define everything else in CSS. With the `toggle` method you won’t even need an `if` statement.

Comment: Well. Thats one Point but I'm trying to learn how to at least reduce this function and learn from it; and if there's another method or proper procedure on how I can reduce something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use CSS to style your elements for each "theme", then just set the theme class on the body:

```js
document.getElementById('switcher').addEventListener('click', (param1) => {
  let isDark = param1.target.value === "Off";

  document.body.classList.toggle('dark', isDark);
  param1.target.value = isDark ? "On" : "Off";
  param1.target.textContent = isDark ? "Dark" : "Light";
})
```

```css
body {
  --lightbg-color: #FFF;
  --lighttxtcolor: #000;
  --darkbg-color: #111;
  --darktxtcolor: #EEE;

  background-color: var(--lightbg-color);
  color: var(--lighttxtcolor);
}

#switcher {
  background-color: var(--lightbg-color);
  color: var(--lighttxtcolor);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: var(--darkbg-color);
  color: var(--darktxtcolor);
}

body.dark #switcher {
  background-color: var(--darkbg-color);
  color: var(--darktxtcolor);
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button id="switcher" value="Off">Light</button>
```

Or, if you want to do it extra fancy, you can use the "theme" class on the body to switch css variable values:

```js
document.getElementById('switcher').addEventListener('click', (param1) => {
  let isDark = param1.target.value === "Off";

  document.body.classList.toggle('dark', isDark);
  param1.target.value = isDark ? "On" : "Off";
  param1.target.textContent = isDark ? "Dark" : "Light";
})
```

```css
body {
  --bg-color: #FFF;
  --txt-color: #000;
  --border-color: #000;
}

body.dark {
  --bg-color: #111;
  --txt-color: #EEE;
  --border-color: #EEE;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

#switcher {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--txt-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
}
```

```html
<button id="switcher" value="Off">Light</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could reduce your code would be to isolate the validation of the current target value, and that value in each of the changes separately.

Also to simplify I created the `color` variable to help minimize the refactoring of the `backgroundColor` and `color` changes

```js
document.getElementById('switcher').addEventListener('click', (param1) => {
    let dmbody = document.body.style;
    let dmbutton = document.getElementById('switcher').style;
    let isOff = param1.target.value == "Off";
    let color = isOff ? "dark" : "light";

    param1.target.value = isOff ? "On" : "Off";
    param1.target.textContent = isOff ? "Dark" : "Light";
    dmbody.backgroundColor = `var(--${color}bg-color)`;
    dmbody.color = `var(--${color}txtcolor)`;
    dmbutton.backgroundColor = `var(--${color}bg-color)`;
    dmbutton.color = `var(--${color}txtcolor)`;
    dmbutton.setProperty("border", `1px solid ${isOff ? "#FFF" : "#000"}`);
})
```

Although this is a refactor way of doing it, I would still prefer @Cerbrus answer